# Is there a way to add custom keyboard shortcuts to EpicEditor

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, epiceditor

I'm basically looking for a way to add custom keyboard shortcuts to EpicEditor.

Let's say I want to run a custom javascript function when I hit CTRL+ENTER.

I also tried using mousetrap, but it doesn't work inside the editor itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var editor = editor.getElement('editor');
editor.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
    alert('test');
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working? I tried `addEventListener` and also `on`. It doesn't seem to fire.